# Error in ajax in jsp and servlets

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, jsp

i have problem with my code.When i run project on localhost:\8081: , It 's OK.
but when I upload to host free . It's not run.

run

[image: run]

not run

[image: not run]

this is code ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#bt").click(function(){
    var user = $("#name").val();
    var pass = $("#pass").val();
    $.ajax({
            url:"${pageContext.request.contextPath}/Authentication?user="+user+ "&pass="+pass ,
            dataType: "json",
            type:"POST",
            success:function(result){
                if(result.abc != "Incorect"){
                    window.location.href="${pageContext.request.contextPath} %>/jsp/mngCoffee.jsp";
                }
                else{
                    alert(result.abc);
                }

            }});
});
```

this is code jsp:

```
'<div>
        <form action="<%=request.getContextPath() %>/Authentication" method="POST">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Login..</legend>
                <label for="name">Username :</label><br/>
                <input type="text" class="inputField"  id="name" name="txtName"/><br/>
                <label for="pass">Password :</label><br/>
                <input type="password" class="inputField" id="pass" name="txtPass"/></br>
                <button id="bt" type="button" >logon</button>

            </fieldset>
        </form>

</div>'
```

this is code servlet:

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    String name = request.getParameter("user");
    String pass = request.getParameter("pass");

    JSONObject o = new JSONObject();

    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        try {
            System.out.println(name);
            System.out.println(pass);

            if(UserDAO.checkUser(name, pass)){

                session.setAttribute("name", name);
            o.put("abc", "success");    
            out.println(o); 
            }
            else{
                o.put("abc", "Incorect");
                out.println(o);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
```

please help!
thank and regard.

Comment: You should post your javascript code and the relevant html.

Comment: Looks like 500 Internal server error.. Please post your relevant code.

Comment: Server threw an exception. Just read server log to find it. The exception itself already represents the whole answer at its own (if you're incapable to interpret it, just copypaste message and 1st line into a search engine).

Answer (score 0):

seem to be error in com.dns.DAO.UserDAO.checkUser(UserDAO.java:62)
line 62 in checkUser() function. Can you recheck the code or post it in here?

Comment: i checked code no problem. when i run on localhost it ok. but when run on host jelastic it error.

Answer (score 0):

check your Database connection classes working fine or not(check username and password)

check in UserDAO.java at line number 62.